# Can't properly rebuild a string with Replacement values from Dictionary

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a file using a template. I am processing the file in a while loop line by line. The first section of the file, first 35 lines are header information. The infromation is surrounded by # signs. Take this string for example:

```
Field InspectionStationID 3 {"PVA TePla #WSM#", "sw#data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#", "#data.context.TOOL_ENTITY#"}
```

The expected output should be:

```
Field InspectionStationID 3 {"PVA TePla", "sw0.2.002", "WSM102"}
```

This header section uses a different mapping than the rest of the file so I wanted to parse the file line by line from top to bottom and use a different logic for each section so that I don't waste time parsing the entire file at once multiple times for different sections.

The logic uses two dictionaries populated from an xml file. Because the file has mutliple tables, I combined them in the two dictionaries like so:

```
var headerCdataIndexKeyVals = Dictionary<string, int>(){
    {"data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION", 1},
    {"data.context.TOOL_ENTITY",0}
};
var headerCdataArrayKeyVals = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var tool_contextCdataList = new list <string>{"HM654", "sw0.2.002"};
var contextCdataList = new List<string>{"WSM102"}
headerCdataArrayKeyVals.add("tool_context", tool_contextCdataList);
headerCdataArrayKeyVals.add("context", contextCdataList);
```

To help me map the values to their respective positions in the string in one go and without having to loop through multiple dictionaries.

I am using the following logic:

```
public static string FindSubsInDelimetersAndReturn(string str, char openDelimiter, char closeDelimiter, HeaderMapperData mapperData )
        {
            string newString = string.Empty;
            // Stores the indices of
            Stack <int> dels = new Stack <int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            {
                var let = str[i];
                // If opening delimeter
                // is encountered
                if (str[i] == openDelimiter && dels.Count == 0)
                {
                    dels.Push(i);
                }

                // If closing delimeter
                // is encountered
                else if (str[i] == closeDelimiter && dels.Count > 0)
                {

                    // Extract the position
                    // of opening delimeter
                    int pos = dels.Peek();

                    dels.Pop();

                    // Length of substring
                    int len = i - 1 - pos;

                    // Extract the substring
                    string headerSubstring = str.Substring(pos + 1, len);
                    bool hasKey = mapperData.HeaderCdataIndexKeyVals.TryGetValue(headerSubstring.ToUpper(), out int headerCdataIndex);
                    string[] headerSubstringSplit = headerSubstring.Split('.');
                    string headerCDataVal = string.Empty;
                    if (hasKey)
                    {
                        if (headerSubstring.Contains("CONTAINER.CONTEXT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            headerCDataVal = mapperData.HeaderCdataArrayKeyVals[headerSubstringSplit[1].ToUpper() + '.' + headerSubstringSplit[2].ToUpper()][headerCdataIndex];
                            //mapperData.HeaderCdataArrayKeyVals[]
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            headerCDataVal = mapperData.HeaderCdataArrayKeyVals[headerSubstringSplit[1].ToUpper()][headerCdataIndex];
                        }
                        string strToReplace = openDelimiter + headerSubstring + closeDelimiter;
                        string sub = str.Remove(i + 1);
                        sub = sub.Replace(strToReplace, headerCDataVal);
                        newString += sub;
                    }
                    else if (headerSubstring == "WSM" && closeDelimiter == '#')
                    {
                        string sub = str.Remove(len + 1);
                        newString += sub.Replace(openDelimiter + headerSubstring + closeDelimiter, "");
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        newString += let;
                    }
                }
                
                
            }
           
            return newString;
        }
    }
```

But my output turns out to be:

```
"\tFie\tField InspectionStationID 3 {\"PVA TePla#WSM#\", \"sw0.2.002\tField InspectionStationID 3 {\"PVA TePla#WSM#\", \"sw#data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#\", \"WSM102"
```

Can someone help understand why this is happening and how I can go about correcting it so I get the output:

```
Field InspectionStationID 3 {"PVA TePla", "sw0.2.002", "WSM102"}
```

Am i even trying to solve this the right way or is there a better cleaner way to do it? Btw if the key is not in the dictionary I replace it with empty string

Comment: `openDelimiter == closeDelimiter` ? Then you don't really need a stack. If you use `str.IndexOf(delimiter)` you don't need to compare each character.

Comment: By the way, c# already has options built in for templating

Comment: @CaiusJard Could you provide me to a link for something like that? I was not aware there was.

Comment: Stuff like the T4 system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2022 or source generators: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/  or using the Razor engine (typically used for making HTML in MVC/Blazor/RazorPages projects) https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/generate-outputs-with-razor-engine-in-dotnet-core